# Dynamic Dropdown values django

Tags: python, django

I want to create a dropdown `Course` of Trainee where only options of values in `CourseName` of Course model would be shown. Currently I have tried some soulutions after browsing. But its not working. My course dropdown disappeared after editing in forms.py. If i remove this line

> Course = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class':'col-sm-4'}), choices=course_obj.get_course_name(), label='Course :')

Then the dropdown would show but with no options

model.py

```
class Course(models.Model):
    CourseID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    CourseName = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    
    class Meta():
        db_table = "Courses"

    def get_course_name(self):
        return self.CourseName



class Trainee(models.Model):     
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Course = models.CharField(max_length=40)

    class Meta():
        db_table = "Trainee"
```

forms.py

```
class TraineeForm(forms.ModelForm):     
    course_obj = Course()

    Name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'col-sm-4'}), label='Name :')
    Course = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class':'col-sm-4'}), choices=course_obj.get_course_name(), label='Course :')
     ........................
```

edit.html

```
<form method="post" class="form-group" type="multipart/form-data">
        {%csrf_token%}

        {% for Name in form.Name %}
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">{{ form.Name.label }}</label>
            {{ Name }}

        </div>
        {% endfor %}

        {% for Course in form.Course %}
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">{{ form.Course.label }}</label>
            {{ form.Course }}

        </div>
        {% endfor %}
```

The Page appears like this
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While looping a BoundField object - `for Name in form.Name` and `for Course in form.Course` in your case, Django loop through its sub widgets. A CharField has one sub widget, which is its self. A ChoiceField has as many sub widgets as its options, which is zero in your case. This is why your page rendered like that.

According to [Django's Doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ChoiceField.choices) on `choices` attribute of `ChoiceField`:

> Either an iterable of 2-tuples to use as choices for this field, enumeration choices, or a callable that returns such an iterable. This argument accepts the same formats as the choices argument to a model field. See the model field reference documentation on choices for more details. If the argument is a callable, it is evaluated each time the field’s form is initialized, in addition to during rendering. Defaults to an empty list.

Try

```
# forms.py
def course_choices():
    return [(course.CourseName, course.CourseName) for course in Course.objects.all()]

class TraineeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    Name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'col-sm-4'}), label='Name :')
    Course = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class':'col-sm-4'}), choices=course_choices, label='Course :')
    class Meta:
        model = Trainee
        fields = ['Name', 'Course']
```

And then in your template:

```
<!-- edit.html -->
<form method="post" class="form-group" type="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">{{ form.Name.label }}</label>
        {{ Name }}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">{{ form.Course.label }}</label>
        {{ form.Course }}
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: can you please explain this code 'def course_choices():
    return [(course.CourseName, course.CourseName) for course in Course.objects.all()]
'

Comment: It is just a function that fetch all courses and wrap their names as a 2-tuple list. A 2-tuple list is expected by `choices` attribute of `ChoiceField`. The first element of the 2-tuple is the value of the `<option>` tag, and the second is the displayed text of the `<option>` tag. Each time a `TraineeForm` is initiated, this function gets called, so that the choices always keep updated.

Answer (score 1):

===== form.py =====

```
class TraineeForm(forms.ModelForm): 
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TraineeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['Course'].widget = forms.Select(choices=Course.objects.values_list('CourseName','CourseName')) 


    class Meta:
        model = Trainee
        fields = "__all__"
```

========= output ===========

[image]